# P/Invoke from C#: Call functions of returned object

Tags: c#, .net, c++-cli, pinvoke, unmanaged

I have a native/unmanaged DLL and it has a "CreateObject" function which returns a pointer to the business object.. so the call would be sth. like:

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
private static extern IntPtr CreateObject();
```

Question:
The object is exposing public-functions like "Connect()" which i want to call, but i don't know how to "map" these calls so i have a simple method-signature like:

```
private bool Connect();
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way to do this is to provide another PInvoke function which calls into a C function that does the method call

```
[DllImport("MyDll.dll", CharSet = CharSet.Auto)]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
private static extern bool Connect(IntPtr businessObject);
```

Then in C you define the following

```
extern "C" {
  bool Connect(Business* pObject) {
    return pObject->Connect();
  }
}
```

Comment: You'd also want to make the calling conventions match.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wrap the C++ objects up in free functions:

```
bool Connect(MyObject* obj)
{
    return obj->Connect();
}
```

and then export these from your DLL.

Alternatively you can make use of the fact that you are compiling with C++/CLI and export a managed C++/CLI class which can be consumed directly by your C# code.